# Irregularities when adding controls to my panel - they show up wherever they want

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, panel

Here's my code:

```
int ypos = 0;

public void X()
{
    MovieItem NewMovie = new MovieItem();
    NewMovie.SearchMovie(txtSearch.Text);
    NewMovie.Location = new Point(0, ypos);
    ypos += 196;

    panel1.Controls.Add(NewMovie);
}
```

After running method X about 4,5 times, the 5th or 6th item added isn't added where it should instead it is loaded wayyyy below.

Image for clarity:

How it looks **CORRECTLY** at the beginning:
[image]

How it looks **WRONG** after a bit:
[image]

What am I doing wrong that it doesn't work that well?

**EDIT:**
I've used breakpoints and discovered that the problem occurs on the fifth movie, when the ypos variable is around 980. Why could this be? It just skips that location it seems.

Comment: Getting a 403 Forbidden on those images.

Comment: Yeah, imgur bugged out. Switch to TinyPic, images should work now. :)

Comment: fyi, both image links point to the same image

Comment: @John: I'm seeing two distinct images here.

Comment: is the `ypos` modified only in this function `X()`?

Comment: Yes naj. That variable is only used this function alone. It's sole purpose is to position my USERCONTROL in order whenever I have to add another instance of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the problem appears when the `AutoScroll` property of panel is set to `true` and the scroll bar is not at its initial position:0. The panel is positionning the controls at `ypos + vertical position of scroll bar`!!

Either set `AutoScroll = false;` before adding `MovieItem` then `true;` after, but this will reset the scroll bar position
or, substract the scroll bar position from `ypos` when setting the location.

Both fix the problem but the 2nd is better (no scroll bar reset):

```
public void X()
{
    int vscrollPos = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;   

    MovieItem NewMovie = new MovieItem();
    NewMovie.SearchMovie(txtSearch.Text);
    NewMovie.Location = new Point(0, ypos - vscrollPos);
    ypos += 196;

    panel1.Controls.Add(NewMovie);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the problem persists. I dont' know what could be the problem.

Comment: Sorry. When I tested, I haven't scrolled the panel, and when I did that the problem was always there. After some digging with Reflector, I think I found a solution. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a MILLION for this answer! How did you figure this out btw?

Comment: I checked the `Class Panel` whith `Reflector` and saw that `PerformLayout()` and/or `OnLayout` methods take into account the value of AutoScroll when proceeding, I stopped there and begin playing with AutoScroll and observing different behaviors which led me to the solution above. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your class structure is, but that empty space looks to be about what the other controls make up. Perhaps somewhere a movie isn't being found, and thus isn't showing anything?

Comment: That's the thing Dark, all of the movies shown in the pics, are movies I've searched for to illustrate this problem and they ARE found. I don't understand why the blank space. Maybe it has something to do with the heigh of the panel and when the content exceeds X height? Am I missing something?